# Slicing by range

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to slice by range in Python and it seems like it's not possible.

```
>>> a='0123456789'
>>> a[range(1,2)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not list
```

Why do I want to do this? I want to define "what to slice" in one part of my script, put that in a variable, and do the actual slicing elsewhere. Like this:

```
myrange=range(1,2)
a='0123456789'
a[myrange] #<-----raises TypeError
```

Is it possible, and if not, how to do something similar correctly and "right"?

Comment: You mean `slice(1, 2)`?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I am new in Python so I ask stupid questions :)

Comment: @KarelBílek No questions are stupid :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Will `slice` do instead of `range`?
If so, you can use it:

```
>>> a = '0123456789'
>>> a[slice(1, 2)]
'1'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using slice() instead of range()

```
mySlice=slice(1,2)
a='0123456789'
a[mySlice]
```

will give you

```
'1'
```

Comment: This is correct too, ovgolovin was slightly faster (I can't accept 2 answers, sorry!)

Answer (score 0):

replace "`,`" with "`:`" in this syntax.

For instance:

```
a = "0123456789"
a[1:2]
```